# How do I use href in while loop?

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to echo out a link from my posts table for each post posted. The correct information is inside the `href` tag when I'm inspecting but I'm unable to click it? Would be very helpful with some information of whats going on here and how could I fix it? This is how I'm trying to do:

Currently I'm getting the Link text as a link **unclickable**.

```
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, userid, postTitle, postDate, postUrl, votes FROM posts ORDER BY votes DESC');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>
<a href="<?php $row['postUrl'] ?>">Link</a>
<?php
}
```

Comment: What exact html is generated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to end your PHP tag or add an `echo`, You must either end your PHP tag at the start of the while loop, And add another PHP tag after the a tag. Or you can add a echo like below! Good Luck!

**TRY THIS!**

```
<?php
$stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT id, userid, postTitle, postDate, postUrl, votes FROM posts ORDER BY votes DESC');
while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
?>
    <a href="<?php echo $row['postUrl']; ?>">Link</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I had closed closed and opened php, forgot to add that have updated post now. Tried your suggestion also still no luck.

Comment: Try now @Emoless96